# Having trouble figuring out what lens will fit my Nikon D3100

Tags: lens, nikon-d3100, compatibility

I've found a Nikkor 35-80mm f/4-5.6 D Macro lens for a good price, but will it fit on my Nikon D3100?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it will fit, but AF won't work (all D lenses rely on an AF motor in the camera body and the D3100 doesn't have one), so if you buy it, you'll only able to use it as a manual focus lens.

Comment: True. But to add on to this answer, any AF-S lenses WILL autofocus on the D3100.